# UIWebView doesn't work anymore

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I re-edit my question, it's for about two weeks that i set up my WebView in my application, everything was going well working together. Yesterday i wanted to just see if the webView is still working even if i didn't change any of the class's code, and boom SIGABRT. I'm on this bug since yesterday and don't understand why it still give my a SIGABRT.I did as advised some changes but still nothing works yet. If someone with advanced skills in objective c can help me please i'am going crazy, here is the log message (i can show all my code if needed, and please feel free to edit an answer so i can rate the good answer in order to help people after me):

```
    here is my code :

  - (void)showWebView;
    {
        //here i call my webview in my RootViewController
        ViewController *WebViewVC = [[ViewController alloc] init];
        [[self navigationController] pushViewController:WebViewVC  animated:YES];
        [WebViewVC pushIt];

    }

//here is my WebViewController.h
        #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
        #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

    @interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
    {
         IBOutlet UIWebView *myWebView;
    }

    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *myWebView;
    -(void)XButton;
    -(void)pushIt;
    @end


    //here is my WebViewController.m
        -(void)pushIt;
    {

        navigation control
        self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;


        self.title = @"*****";
        myWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
        [self.view addSubview:myWebView];
        [self XButton];
        [self WebViewBrowserBackButton];

        NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSString *defaults = [prefs stringForKey:@"myKey"];
        NSString *defaults2 = [prefs stringForKey:@"mySecondKey"];
        NSString *username = defaults; 
        NSString *password = defaults2;
        NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"**************"]; 
        NSString* body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"************",      username,     password];  
        NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url     cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:30];
        request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
        request.HTTPBody = [body dataUsingEncoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy];

        [myWebView loadRequest:request];
    }


  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "MyWebViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.'



   *** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x017e15e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x015648b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x017e13bb +[NSException raise:format:] + 139
    3   UIKit                               0x005fd6e6 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 505
    4   UIKit                               0x005fddad -[UIViewController loadView] + 302
    5   UIKit                               0x005fe0ae -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 78
    6   UIKit                               0x005fe5b4 -[UIViewController view] + 35
    7   LockScreen                          0x00011596 -[MyWebViewController pushIt] + 246
    8   LockScreen                          0x00003c0a -[RootViewController showWebView] + 202
    9   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x015767d2 -[NSObject performSelector:] + 62
    10  LockScreen                          0x00007f02 -[LCYDataBackedTableView tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] + 130
    11  UIKit                               0x005cc7b1 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1513
    12  UIKit                               0x005cc924 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 279
    13  UIKit                               0x005d0908 __38-[UITableView touchesEnded:withEvent:]_block_invoke + 43
    14  UIKit                               0x00507183 ___afterCACommitHandler_block_invoke + 15
    15  UIKit                               0x0050712e _applyBlockToCFArrayCopiedToStack + 403
    16  UIKit                               0x00506f5a _afterCACommitHandler + 532
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x017a94ce __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x017a941f __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 399
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x01787344 __CFRunLoopRun + 1076
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x01786ac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x017868db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x02a659e2 GSEventRunModal + 192
    23  GraphicsServices                    0x02a65809 GSEventRun + 104
    24  UIKit                               0x004ead3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    25  LockScreen                          0x0000297d main + 125
    26  libdyld.dylib                       0x0208970d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: `loaded the "MyWebViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set`  you need to set outlet of webView

Comment: What changes did you make?
What does your code look like?
Also, make sure that the outlet of "view" for the "MyWebViewController" nib is still connected, and connected to the right object.

Comment: The changes i made are, to "try" to connect my IBOutlet with the xib file, and a initWithNibName in my view call. I will dit my question Timothy Groote, in order to show you my code. Thanks for the answer :).

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIWebView "SIGABRT" in Objective c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19926277/uiwebview-sigabrt-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 1):

Connect the view property of WebViewController from nib file to File's Owner's view object.

The exception trace clearly shows that your view in nib is not connected.

Comment: i try to but never manage to, i did see tutorials to how to do that but couldn't mimic that. And why it was working back then, this is blowing my mind :O. Thanks for answering :) sir.

Comment: open nib file.. Select your webview.. in the right menu, click top right tab which is reference inspector tab.. from that tab click and drag the circle associated with 'view' and drop dragging on File's Owner and then select 'view'

Comment: I get this now :O :  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<MyWebViewController 0xab4db70> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key delegate.'

Comment: i did exactly what you tell me to do :§.